# SwiftUI - Date formating (leading zeros)

Tags: swift, date, formatting

So.. My problem is: I need to parse the following string (response from a request) - "PT9H" to "09.00"
So far I have the following code:

```
    let input = "PT9H"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "'PT'HH'H'"

    let date = formatter.date(from: input)
    let time = "\(Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date)).\(Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date))"
    return "\(time)"
```

The result I get is: "9.0", I need the leading zeros in the result like: "09:00". Any ideas? Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: "PT9H" is a duration formatted in ISO 8601, not a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go about formatting the value somehow like this:

```
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date)
let min = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date)

let time = String(format: "%02d:%02d", hour, min)
```

However, this *will not work* in different timezones equally and will create issues since the API response is not a date but a duration.